# ToList, FirstOrDefault, AsQueryable Not Found on Runtime-Compiled Code - MongoDb Driver

Tags: vb.net, mongodb

MongoDB Legacy Driver (Latest Version)
VB.Net

I'm using CodeDom Compilation to compile and run a script at run-time. The script will access MongoDB. I've had success with everything, until I get to the point where I am using a ToList, FirstOrDefault, AsQueryable method on a Mongodb Cursor.

When I add the following code to the host assembly, the process functions flawlessly.

```
Function process_item(ByVal msg As queue_message, _
                                ByVal job As queue_job, _
                                ByVal invMongoDatabaseSec As MongoDatabase) As object

    Dim sColl = invMongoDatabaseSec.GetCollection(Of people)("people")
    Dim s = sColl.Find(Query.EQ("_id", "Some_Id_Here")).FirstOrDefault
    return s

End Function
```

I also tested to make sure the compiler was communicating with MongoDB correctly by making the slight modification below, and had success.

```
Function process_item(ByVal msg As queue_message, _
                                ByVal job As queue_job, _
                                ByVal invMongoDatabaseSec As MongoDatabase) As object

    Dim sColl = invMongoDatabaseSec.GetCollection(Of people)("people")
    Dim s as people = sColl.FindOne(Query.EQ("_id", "Some_Id_Here"))
    return s

End Function
```

However, when I put the exact same code in the runtime compiler, the .FirstOrDefault throws an error: *Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.MissingMemberException: Public member 'ToList' on type 'MongoCursor(Of people)' not found.*

I understand that compiled code runs in an alternative AppDomain, and I have accounted for all assembiles that have been loaded into the host.

```
For Each a In Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()
    vbParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(Assembly.Load(a).Location)
Next
```

I have the exact same "Imports" referenced in both places. Paying particular attention to the MongoDB, and System.Collections.Generic (which I know the ToList, etc are derived from).

I'm pretty sure I'm missing a reference somewhere, but for the life of me, I can't figure out what it is. Is there a reference, or Import that I am missing? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
Imports System
Imports MongoDB
Imports MongoDB.Driver
Imports MongoDB.Driver.Linq
Imports MongoDB.Bson
Imports MongoDB.Driver.Builders
Imports mongodb.driver.legacy
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Caching
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic 
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports system.data
```